# Multiple sequential api calls RxJs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, request

I need to make sequential api calls using RxJs. The thing is that first Observable emits an array, for each item of this array I should set a custom url in order to make the next call. In the second call I should check some conditions and return Observable.
My question is, how can I make a call for each element of array as it's url changes?

I tried something like this, but it only sets the url for the last item, not for each.

```
  private func(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.service
      .getItems()
      .pipe(
        map((response) => response.items),
        mergeMap((result) => {
          result.map((order) =>
            this.orderService.setCustomUrl(order.number)
          );
          return this.orderService.getItems().pipe(
            mergeMap((response) => {
              if (response.items.some((item) => item.number === this.model.number)) {
                return of(true);
              } else {
                return of(false);
              }
            }),
          );
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: is `orderService.setCustomUrl` performing a http request? if not, do you mind updating your question with its code?

Comment: @TheFabio no, this method is just for setting the url, it's not performing any calls to backend.

Comment: What is the point of this piece of code`result.map((order) =>
            this.orderService.setCustomUrl(order.number)
          )`. The result of the `map` operation is not stored anywhere.

Comment: @Picci yeah, I know, this was intended to be my question, because I don't know, how to set the url for each order and pass this information to the next Observable (sorry, my knowledge of RxJs is still weak). Actually this value should be stored in this.orderService.customUrl after I set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you invoke `setCustomUrl()` but you don't use `.getItems()` until after the `map()` has completed. So by the time you invoke `.getItems()` the service has received the last item from your `.map()`.

You can use the following code to get the desired result.

```
function func(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.service
    .getItems()
    .pipe(
      map((response) => response.items),
      switchMap(items => from(items).pipe(
        concatMap(item=>{
          this.orderService.setCustomUrl(item.number);
          return this.orderService.getItems().pipe(
            map(response => response.items.some((item) => item.number === this.model.number))
          );
        }),
        toArray()
      )),
      map(items => items.some(item => item))
    );
}
```

The `from()` operator turns an array, and emits each value individually. This is where we pipe in and return the `.some()` boolean.

The `toArray()` takes all of those values and turns it back into an array.

Then we do one last `map()` to see if all items are true.

Comment: wow, that's really helpful, thanks a lot! One more question, how can I stop the Observable whenever it finds a first match? Should I use take(1) or first() operator?

Comment: You could use `takeUntil()` and set the condition to the first match.

Comment: Given the problem you are exposing, I think you may find [this one](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) an interesting read

Comment: @Picci cool, thanks!

Comment: Right, it should be `concatMap()` instead of `mergeMap()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: For the sake of educational transparency, the original problem with `mergeMap()` is that it will invoke the `setCustomUrl()` method for all items immediately. This means when we invoke `getItems()` on the next line, we may not get our expected value.  With `concatMap()`, the sequence is more synchronous. `concatMap()` will wait until the current item receives a value from `getItems()` before moving on to the next item and invoking `setCustomUrl()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening in your code:

```
        {
          // for each "result" array element, call "this.orderService.setCustomUrl(order.number)"
          result.map((order) =>
            this.orderService.setCustomUrl(order.number)
          );
          // assuming "setCustomUrl" is setting the one variable, this will cause only the last "order.number" to be set at this point here

          // then this last part executes once and returns the boolean only for the last order
          return this.orderService.getItems().pipe(
            mergeMap((response) => {
              if (response.items.some((item) => item.number === this.model.number)) {
                return of(true);
              } else {
                return of(false);
              }
            }),
          );
        }
```

I think the intention is to verify if any order returned by `this.orderService.getItems()` using `order.number` have the item number from `this.model.number` so you should instead do something like this:

first change your service call so it can use the order number like this `this.orderService.getItems(order.number)`

then the following:

```
private func(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.service
      .getItems()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((orders) =>
          from(orders.items).pipe(
// for each item on the initial response return an observable,
// mapping its result to a boolean as your initial function
            mergeMap((order) =>
              this.orderService
                .getItems(order.number)
                .pipe(map((itemsResponse) => itemsResponse.items.some((item) => item.number === this.model.number)))
            )
          )
        ),
// this will get all the observable boolean values and only yield when all resolve
        toArray(),
// this aggregates all boolean vals into one
        map((all) => all.some((x) => x)),
// and we complete the subscription after first yield
        take(1)
      )
```

Comment: updated with tested and commented answer